# Android WebView fails at loading URL stating net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCE

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

I am using a WebView in my application and upon the click of a button the user is supposed to go from '**URL A**' to '**URL B**' , but it looks like the WebView makes an effort- I see **URL B** in the background of the loader but within a fraction of seconds it loops back to '**URL A**'. When I checked the android studio log I found an error stating **net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES** .

No where else in my application have I noticed such a glitch and there are so many urls the user can go to and fro with no backfire.

The **URL B** a grid showing a maximum of 10 photos. Hence I don't feel its heavy on resources. **URL A** has a list of more photos and data in it. What could be the possible cause for such an error?

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @kgandroid I believe android WebViews use a Chrome based rendering engine

Comment: Tis happens when you try to load a lot of resources in webview

Comment: What would be considered to be a lot, Because as I mentioned earlier I have pages with more components and works with ease.

Is there any possible way to track the load in webview?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when chrome tries to load a large number of images/resources in a short period of time.Have a look at [this.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108055)

Try disabling the chrome plugin **adblock plus** and try.Still it may take long time to load

Comment: The URL B has barely tow or three image thumbnails. It seemed very low on sizes too.
Would you mind explaining what adblock plus could possibly have to do with this?